# Rails cancan, giving permission to read if record is associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have the snippet below:

```
  can :read, Task do |task|
    cus = task.case.case_users.ids

    cus.each do |id|
      cu = CaseUser.find(id)
      cu.user_id === user.id
    end
  end
```

Each case has many tasks.  This is authorization for the task, so I want to get the tasks's case.  Each case has a `case_user`.  I want to be sure that before giving permission to read the task, that there is a `case_user` record with a `user_id` equal to the user passed through by cancan.

How can I find the task's related case, the case's related case_users, and allow `:read` if the user's id is in the case_users array of records?

When testing it in the console, it returns false, however, cancan still gives authorization to read the record when it should not be.

Edit:

I have tried adding this `readable` method to the `Task` model below:

```
def readable?(user_id, task_id)
  Task.find(task_id).case.case_users.ids.each do |id|
    cu = CaseUser.find(id)

    if cu.user_id === user_id
        true
    end
  end
end
```

And I have this in the `initialize` method in the `Ability` class:

```
  can :read, Task do |task|
    task.readable?(user.id, task.id)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
can :read, Task, :case=> { :user_id => user.id }
```

If you're using CanCan > 1.4, then in your view:

```
<% if can? :read, @case => Task %>
```

Taken from [the CanCan Wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources#accessing-parent-in-ability).

Answer (score 0):

I would move the logic into your model and do something like this in your cancan ability.rb:

```
can :read, Task do |task|
  task.readable_by_user? user
end
```

Then add a readable_by_user? function to your model that returns true or false like this:

```
def readable_by_user?(user)
  case.case_users.include? user
end
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.  I need to go to the task record's parent case, and to the case record's parent case_users (that's a model).  When I have the task's case's case_users, I want to iterate over each one of them and allow the read action if the user trying to authorize is in the case_users user_ids.